# Why is there no compiler or analyzer warning when an IDisposable object is not disposed within a method?

Tags: c#, idisposable

Example code:

```
internal class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Foo foo = new Foo();
    }
}

public class Foo : IDisposable
{
    public void Dispose()
    {
        // Not invoked.
        Console.WriteLine("Foo disposed");
    }
}
```

Here the Foo type is IDisposable, but the 'foo' variable is not wrapped in a 'using' statement; either the traditional syntax with a 'using' block/scope, or the newer syntax that calls Dispose() when the variable goes out of scope, like so:

```
using Foo foo = new Foo();
```

Given that this could be a source of resource leaks, why is there no compiler warning or analyzer rule for this scenario?

This seems like an obvious thing to check, and therefore I suspect this omission is for a good reason.

Comment: You mean something like [CA2000](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/fundamentals/code-analysis/quality-rules/ca2000)? The way to configure and enable analyzers has varied with versions of .NET, but this is one of the oldest and most venerable rules.

Comment: Thanks. I will look, but it appears to be disabled by default(?). I.e. a new empty project with the above code doesn't report this warning.

Comment: I can only speculate, but it seems there are plenty of ways how this could be made safe without the compiler really noticing. For a start, both flavours of `using` are just syntactic sugar; you can also call `Dispose()` manually. Then, some classes offer methods that internally call `Dispose()` (such as the `Close()` method of some I/O classes). Then, the ctor of a disposable class *could* register itself on the app exit event, for instance, to make sure it gets cleaned up. And ultimately, certain classes (like `MemoryStream`) inherit `IDisposable`, but are actually safe to use without ...

Comment: ... disposal, as far as I know (because it's essentially just an array wrapped into a `Stream` subclass).

Comment: @O.R.Mapper I think those scenarios you present would be a good candidate for enabling this rule by default and relying on rule suppressions when you don't want it. But yes, thanks for your thoughts on this. Interesting, the rule for Disposable /fields/ on objects has special cases for Stream and other classes https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/code-analysis/quality-rules/ca2213

Comment: @redcalx: Yes, according to the docs, some of those cases are listed as "when to suppress the warning". Maybe over time, MS realized the special cases became too numerous? As I said, I can only speculate here; I might still post the above as an answer, though, if no other answers arrive in the next couple of days.

Answer (score 2):

*EDIT: Removed the bad example that ignored the `leaveOpen` constructor argument of `StreamWriter`. Upon rethinking it, I also realized the data would remain unflushed unless `Dispose` was called so disposing was the right call there.*

I am quite sure it is because you do not always want to `Dispose` objects. For example `Task` objects are `IDisposable`, but you normally never dispose of them explicitly. There are probably more types like this, i.e. types that only rarely allocate unmanaged resources and which should only be disposed if their finalizers are slowing down your application.

Furthermore, if your class has unmanaged resources that need to be disposed no matter what, then it should be implementing the [Dispose Pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/garbage-collection/implementing-dispose) by using finalizers, not relying on someone not forgetting to write `using`.

Comment: While I can appreciate the *"you do not always want to dispose objects"* sentiment, your example is doing the wrong thing. `StreamWriter` has a constructor that takes a `leaveOpen` parameter which should be `true` so that you can dispose the `StreamWriter` without it disposing the `stream` provided to it.

Comment: @madreflection You are right, I edited the answer

Comment: Much better. I'm going to leave the comment, but only because it gives context to the history and the "EDIT:" note, and I think there's value in that.